# C++: When deleting a dynamically allocated class, do private members that aren't on the heap get deleted as well?

Tags: c++, memory-management

For Example, let's say you have:

```
Class Test
{
     public:
     Test();
     private:
     int x = 0;
     int y = 3;
}
```

You declare an instance of Test using something like

```
Test * RRR = new Test();
```

Let's say somewhere down the line you type

```
delete RRR;
```

Does this also delete the memory that x and y took up?

Comment: It is best to post examples you have compiled.  Try using an onlime compiler before posting your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short answer is yes, but strictly speaking, x and y are not **deleted**. The memory they tak will be released, because they are data members of the struct.

Even you don't define a destructor, the compiler will synthesized a default destructor for you, which will release the memory that the struct takes.

Comment: Even without the class itself having a deconstructor?

Comment: @RemyLeBeau You mean the destructor, yes, because since you deleted `RRR`, the memory for it will be erase despite it having a destructor or not.

Comment: Yes.  When a class is destructed, the memory used for its members is automatically reclaimed, whether you specify a destructor or not. In this case, your members are value types, so no additional destructions are needed. Members that are class types are auto-destructed.  You only need to specify a destructor if you have members that need to be explicitly destructed, like pointers to other member and objects that were dynamically allocated/instantiated.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, it is on the heap, not stack. But my explanation still stands. :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's okay and thanks everyone above for all the help, just one more question though, If I WERE to have a class and/or pointers as private members of my Test Class and I DID have a destructor that deleted those classes and/or pointers, when I call delete on 'RRR' will it automatically call on that destructor?

Comment: @RemyLeBeau Yup. It always calls the destructor.